# Como creo un diccionario con multiples values ej. una lista o tuple, para cada key?

Tags: python

Tengo 2 listas

```
lista_nom = [['Luisa Cordoba'], ['Olga Leiva'], ['Graciela Sanchez']]

lista_mate = [['CIENCIAS', 7.2, 'MATEMATICAS', 9.0, 'ALGEBRA', 6.5, 'FISICA', 2.1, 'QUIMICA', 1.7], ['CIENCIAS', 4.5, 'MATEMATICAS', 9.8, 'ALGEBRA', 5.7, 'FISICA', 8.2, 'QUIMICA', 9.1], ['CIENCIAS', 7.0, 'MATEMATICAS', 3.3, 'ALGEBRA', 5.7, 'FISICA', 6.7, 'QUIMICA', 9.0]]
```

Manualmente iterando sobre `lista_nom[x]` y `lista_mate[x:10]` la siguiente linea me crea una entrada del diccionario deseado pero como hago para ir agregando cada entrada en el diccionario ?

```
diccio_fin = dict(zip(lista_nom[0], lista_mate[0:10]))

{'Luisa Cordoba': ['CIENCIAS', 7.2, 'MATEMATICAS', 9.0, 'ALGEBRA', 6.5, 'FISICA', 2.1, 'QUIMICA', 1.7]}

diccio_fin = dict(zip(lista_nom[1], lista_mate[1:10]))

{'Olga Leiva': ['CIENCIAS', 4.5, 'MATEMATICAS', 9.8, 'ALGEBRA', 5.7, 'FISICA', 8.2, 'QUIMICA', 9.1]}

diccio_fin = dict(zip(lista_nom[2], lista_mate[2:10]))

{'Graciela Sanchez': ['CIENCIAS', 7.0, 'MATEMATICAS', 3.3, 'ALGEBRA', 5.7,
  'FISICA', 6.7, 'QUIMICA', 9.0]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que lo que buscas es esto:

```
diccio_fin = dict((e[0][0],e[1]) for e in zip(lista_nom, lista_mate))
print(diccio_fin)

{'Luisa Cordoba': ['CIENCIAS', 7.2, 'MATEMATICAS', 9.0, 'ALGEBRA', 6.5, 'FISICA', 2.1, 'QUIMICA', 1.7], 'Olga Leiva': ['CIENCIAS', 4.5, 'MATEMATICAS', 9.8, 'ALGEBRA', 5.7, 'FISICA', 8.2, 'QUIMICA', 9.1], 'Graciela Sanchez': ['CIENCIAS', 7.0, 'MATEMATICAS', 3.3, 'ALGEBRA', 5.7, 'FISICA', 6.7, 'QUIMICA', 9.0]}
```

- Combinamos cada elemento de ambas lista en una tupla con `zip(lista_nom, lista_mate)`
- Recorremos cada caso con una "comprensión de listas `e[0][0]` será la clave y `e[1]` el valor